# OrientDB Database import failed

Tags: database, orientdb, database-restore, orientdb-2.1

I've created an OrientDB backup with the following command:

```
./backup.sh plocal:../databases/DemoDB demo demo demo.zip
```

Now, to test if my backup succeeded, I've removed and recreated my database, and I'm now importing it using the console:

```
IMPORT DATABASE "/Users/erik/databases/demo.zip"
```

I'm now greeted with the following error:

```
Started import of database 'plocal:../databases/BestProgrammingBooks' from /Users/erik/databases/demo.zip...
Non merge mode (-merge=false): removing all default non security classes
Removed 0 classes.Error on database import happened just before line 299, column 444
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "22Vp"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.OJSONReader.nextChar(OJSONReader.java:273)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.OJSONReader.readNext(OJSONReader.java:174)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.OJSONReader.readString(OJSONReader.java:92)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.OJSONReader.readString(OJSONReader.java:87)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.OJSONReader.readString(OJSONReader.java:83)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport.importDatabase(ODatabaseImport.java:423)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.console.OConsoleDatabaseApp.importDatabase(OConsoleDatabaseApp.java:1711)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.console.OGremlinConsole.importDatabase(OGremlinConsole.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.execute(OConsoleApplication.java:392)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.executeCommands(OConsoleApplication.java:253)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.console.OConsoleApplication.run(OConsoleApplication.java:142)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.console.OGremlinConsole.main(OGremlinConsole.java:64)

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseExportException: Error on importing database 'BestProgrammingBooks' from file: /Users/erik/databases/demo.zip
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "22Vp
```

What's going on her, and how can I fix this?? I'm using OrientDB 2.1.5 on a Mac.

Comment: Hi Erik, do you have a way to send us your database to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Hi Erik, have you already tried to export the DB from studio before deleting it ? I also wanted to ask you what "22Vp" represents in your DB.

Comment: I have no idea what 22Vp means, it's not something which means something for me. And no, I haven't used the export from DB studio, I only used backup.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a backup, to restore the database the right operation is RESTORE, not IMPORT. IMPORT is when you want to import a database previously exported with EXPORT command.

For more information look at: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Backup-and-Restore.html